# AndEngine: Failed loading Bitmap in AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource. AssetPath: gfx/splash.png

Tags: java, android, andengine, game-engine

Im kind of new to Android games and AndEngine, so ive forked a project with AndEngine allready installed. https://github.com/vimvim/AndEngine-AndroidStudio. i forked this project, deleted the Examples module, and created my own file , and set its activity to the Launcher activity, i can find all of them classes from AndEngine but when i run the project i cannot find the splash.png file .
my code for loading it is the following:

```
  BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    splashTextureAtlas = new   BitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    splash_region =  BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(splashTextureAtlas, activity, "splash.png", 0, 0);
    splashTextureAtlas.load();
```

And it runs fine right up until i cannot find the splash.png file.

my structure in the project is:

```
 -myapplication 
   -build
   -libs
   -src
      -main
         -assets
            -gfx
               -splash.png
         -java
         -res
         -AndroidManifest.xml
```

My Exception:

```
4642-4663/kristian.niclas.matti.myapp E/AndEngine﹕ Failed loading Bitmap in AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource. AssetPath: gfx/splash.png
java.io.FileNotFoundException: gfx/splash.png
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:313)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:287)
        at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.create(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:52)
        at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.create(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:43)
        at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.java:86)
        at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.java:82)
        at kristian.niclas.matti.myapp.ResourcesManager.loadSplashScreen(ResourcesManager.java:161)
        at kristian.niclas.matti.myapp.SceneManager.createSplashScene(SceneManager.java:79)
        at kristian.niclas.matti.myapp.GameActivity.onCreateScene(GameActivity.java:57)
        at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$3.onCreateResourcesFinished(BaseGameActivity.java:171)
        at kristian.niclas.matti.myapp.GameActivity.onCreateResources(GameActivity.java:40)
        at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreateGame(BaseGameActivity.java:183)
        at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onSurfaceCreated(BaseGameActivity.java:112)
        at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(EngineRenderer.java:80)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1500)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

ive had this problem for several hours now :) so any help would be greatly apriciated.

Solution:

1.Delete your project.
2. Download code at link:http://themakeinfo.com/2015/03/andengine-template-for-android-studio-2/

3.unzip + import project.

4. Make some code and run :)

Answer (score 0):

Try taking your splash.png out of the 'gfx' folder and don't set a base path.  So just load splash.png from the 'assest' folder.

If that doesn't work, I would drop another image into the assets folder, any random image, called image.png and try and open that.

If that doesn't work there must be something wrong with the set up of your project as the 'assets' directory is not being found.  Are you using eclipse?  Your structure looks like the 'assets' folder is inside the 'src' folder, that should not be the case, the 'assets' folder should be on the same level as the 'src' folder not inside any other directory.  Of course if you are not using eclipse perhaps a different IDE has a different structure but it still seems wrong to me.

Comment: Hello. i ran into all sorts of problems, it wasnt just limited to this. To those just wanting to get started with android game development, and has alot of trouble with AndEngine setup like i had, i surgest that you folllow this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJcm5Oyi3YA which is just normal android game development.     I followed the AndEngine trail, and ended up in a bunch of deadends, having to setup NDK for android studio is a real pain. since im not concerned with this problem anymore, and anit gonna try your solution im afraid i cant accept it. thanks anyway though.